# Coffeescript & Jquery remove element after animation

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, slidetoggle, removechild

I'm trying to remove an element on click, however remove stops the `slideToggle` from happening.

```
$('.js-preview-close').click ->
$('.js-preview-container').slideToggle(1000).remove();
```

I believe I need to do a callback from within `slideToggle`, but I just switched to Coffescript and am not sure how to write it. If it were jQuery could it just be:

```
$('.js-preview-container').slideToggle(300, function(){$(this).remove()});
```

How do I do this in Coffeescript? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.js-preview-container').slideToggle 300, ->
  @remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

In CoffeeScript the `@` replaces the `this` keyword. So try this:

```
$('.js-preview-container').slideToggle 300, -> @remove()
```